# Different ways of iterating over linked list

Tags: c++, c, linked-list

The first thing I think of when iterating over a linked list is to do this:

```
Node* node = head;

while (node)
{
    // do something to node
    node = node->next;
}
```

But sometimes I see people do this complicated thing:

```
Node** node = &head;

while (*node)
{
    // do something to node
    node = &(*node)->next;
}
```

What is the difference and what is the second one used for?

Comment: This is a good case for looking at the actual assembly code.  Its ok if you don't understand it at first, just the delta in number of  lines of assembly is a reasonable indicator.  I often paste small samples into http://gcc.godbolt.org/ Its has filters that makes it more convenient than compiling with -S and then viewing the unfiltered results)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You obviously understand the first method.

The fundamental difference between the first and second is where the pointer's used to enumerate the list reside. In the first, the pointer *values* are used via a local variable, each time updating it to the value of the current node's `next` pointer. In the second, a pointer-to-pointer is used to hold the address of the "current" pointer. The pointer it addresses is an actual pointer "in the list", not just it's value. Initially it addresses the `head` pointer. With each step it addresses the current node's `next` pointer. When the algorithm finishes it will be holding the address of the *last* `next` member in the linked list, the value of which better be NULL.

The second has distinct advantages, though none for simple enumeration. This method is more commonly utilized in maintenance scenarios, such as positional list insertions and removals.

Example: Given only a head pointer to a linked list with the following node-form, write a function that appends a new node to the end of the list:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

Using the first method to enumerate requires maintaining a previous pointer and a special-consideration to detect an initial NULL head pointer. The following function does that, and always returns the head of the linked list:

```
struct Node * ll_insertTail(struct Node *head, int data)
{
    struct Node *prev = NULL, *cur = head;

    while (cur)
    {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    cur = malloc(sizeof(*head));
    cur->data = data;
    cur->next = NULL;

    if (prev == NULL)
        return cur;

    prev->next = cur;
    return head;
}
```

The same operation, but utilizing a pointer-to-pointer approach to walk the actual pointer members (not just their values) would be something like this:

```
struct Node* ll_insertTail(struct Node *head, Type data)
{
    struct Node **pp = &head;

    while (*pp)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    *pp = malloc(sizeof(**pp));
    (*pp)->data = data;
    (*pp)->next = NULL;

    return head;
}
```

This could be further enhanced by requiring the caller pass the address of the head pointer in the first place. This adds he advantage of allowing you to utilize the return value of the function for something other than the list head pointer. For example:

```
int ll_insertTail(struct Node **pp, int data)
{
    while (*pp)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    if ((*pp = malloc(sizeof(**pp))) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate linked list node");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    (*pp)->data = data;
    (*pp)->next = NULL;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Invoked as:

```
    int res = ll_insertTail(&head, data);
```

Both of the latter cases are possible because of utilizing pointers by-address rather than simply by-value. For simple enumeration it makes little sense to exercise a pointer-to-pointer approach. But if you need to search for a specific node or position of a node within a list **and** retain a mechanism for using the pointer that got you there (could be `head`, could be some `next` member), pointers-to-pointers make for elegant solutions.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

In the first code sample, the variable `node` is a pointer to a `Node` struct. It contains the address of the memory location where the `Node` struct is stored.

In the second code sample, the variable `node` is a pointer to a pointer to a `Node` struct. It contains the address of a memory location containing the address of a memory location where the `Node` struct is stored.

This sounds confusing in large part because the variable name is the same in both code samples and it is almost the same as `Node`. Let's rewrite the code samples so that the meaning of the pointer is clearer.

First case:

```
Node* node_pointer = head;

while (node_pointer != NULL) {
    // node_pointer points to a Node
    // do something to that Node, then advance to the next element in the list
    // ... something ...
    node_pointer = node_pointer->next;  // advance
}
```

Second case:

```
Node** node_pointer_pointer = &head;

while (*node_pointer_pointer != NULL) {
    // node_pointer_pointer points to a pointer which points to a Node
    // do something to that Node, then advance to the next element in the list
    // ... something ...
    node_pointer_pointer = &((*node_pointer_pointer)->next);  // advance
}
```

In both cases, the variable `head` is a pointer to a `Node` struct. That's why its value is assigned directly to `node_pointer` in the first case:

```
node_pointer = head;
```

And in the second case, the `&` operator is used to get the memory location of `head`:

```
node_pointer_pointer = &head;
```

What is a `Node`? It is a [struct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29) containing (probably along with other things) a field `next` which is a pointer to a `Node`. That is why the value of `next` can be assigned directly to `node_pointer` in the first code sample but it has to be referenced with the `&` operator in the second code sample.

Why is the second approach useful? In this example, it's not. If you only want to iterate over the elements of the linked list, all you need is a pointer to a `Node` struct.

However, it is useful to have a pointer to a pointer when you want to manipulate the subordinate pointer. For example, suppose you have finished traversing the list, and now you want to add a new node to the tail.

In the first case above, `node_pointer` is of no help because its value is `NULL`. You can't do anything more with it.

In the second case, while the value of `*node_pointer_pointer` is `NULL`, the value of `node_pointer_pointer` is not. It is the address of the `next` field of the last node in the list. Therefore, we can assign the address of a new `Node` struct to that `next`:

```
*node_pointer_pointer = make_new_node();  // make_new_node() returns a pointer
```

Note the asterisk, or dereferencing operator, in `*node_pointer_pointer`. By deferencing `node_pointer_pointer`, we get the `next` pointer, and we can assign to it the address of a new `Node` struct.

Also note that this assignment works if `node_pointer_pointer` points to the head of an empty list. Dereferencing it gets us `head`, and we can assign to it the address of a new `Node` struct.